# Is sending an HTTP request to an api to send an email secure?

Tags: rest, http, email, nodemailer

I'm planning to create an API using express that I would send an http request from the client-side to send emails. I want to send these emails to verify my customer's emails. I'm not sure if that would be secure because someone could possibly modify the code on the client-side and use that to get around the verification. I don't know if that could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can protect your API so that it only accepts requests from an authorized client, Web or Mobile. In this way you are mitigating that calls from unauthorized sources violate your API.
To give you an idea, I leave here some reference articles.
https://auth0.com/blog/node-js-and-express-tutorial-building-and-securing-restful-apis/

Answer (score 0):

We need a context regarding verifying email.

Do you want to verify the email during a new account creation? Do you want to verify the email during login process? Do you want to verify the email for newsletter purpose?

Rule of thumb, even if you check email value just after user fills in, I recommend you to verify the email one more time before finalizing your process in your system.

The reason is that the steps on client-side are for UX related. Anybody, make a  request to your endurl with abused payload.

Comment: I want to verify the email during account creation

Comment: You can create the account with status "PENDING" and send email, in server side, with a unique code to verify the email later. When user clicks the link in the email, in your backend you change the status to "CONFIRMED" by checking the unique code. 

In this case, you make sure that the user has this email filled in during account creation.  
Not sure if you want to do by yourself, you can use firebase authentication, it does everything for you.